# How to bound this sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Consider $a_{n\:=\:}1\:+\sum _{k=1}^n\:\frac{2+k}{3^k+1}$.
I want to show this sequence convrege using the Cauchy-theorem.
So far this is what i wrote:
Let $\epsilon \:>\:0$. we need to find that $N$ so that $\forall n,m\:>\:N$ $\left|a_{m\:}-\:a_n\right|\:<\:\epsilon $.
$\left|a_{m\:}-\:a_n\right|\:=\:\left|1\:+\:\sum _{k=0}^m\:\frac{k+1}{3^k+1}\:-\:1\:+\:\sum \:_{k=0}^n\:\frac{k+1}{3^k+1}\:\right|\:=\:\left|\sum _{k=n+1}^m\frac{k+1}{3^k+1}\:\right|\:<\:\left|\sum \:_{k=n+1}^m\frac{k+1}{3^k}\right|\:<\left|\sum \:\:_{k=n+1}^m\frac{2^k}{3^k}\right|\:\:=\:\left|\sum \:\:_{k=n+1}^m\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k\right|$.
But from here i stuck. how to continue from here? how can i bounded more to show is less then epsilon? tnx!

Comment: Geometric series formula?

Comment: @DavidMitra but how you get rid of the "m"?

Comment: $\sum_{k=n}^m r^k={r^n-r^{m+1}\over 1-r }$. Alternatively, just use the fact that your final series is convergent; thus Cauchy.

Comment: @DavidMitra i just don't get you. How can you bound $\left|a_{m\:}-\:a_n\right|\:=\:\left|1\:+\:\sum _{k=0}^m\:\frac{k+1}{3^k+1}\:-\:1\:+\:\sum \:_{k=0}^n\:\frac{k+1}{3^k+1}\:\right|\:=\:\left|\sum _{k=n+1}^m\frac{k+1}{3^k+1}\:\right|\:<\:\left|\sum \:_{k=n+1}^m\frac{k+1}{3^k}\right|\:<\left|\sum \:\:_{k=n+1}^m\frac{2^k}{3^k}\right|\:\:=\:\left|\sum \:\:_{k=n+1}^m\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k\right|$ using only $n$, NOT $n$ and $m$. the geomtric series don't work here or maybe im wrong..

Comment: Do it this way: we have $$\sum_{k=n+1}^m (2/3)^k\le\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (2/3)^k=(2/3)^{n+1}/ (1-2/3)=3\cdot(2/3)^{n+1}.$$ This is small if $n$ is big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $m>n$
 . You have$$a_{m}-a_{n}=\underset{k=n+1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}\frac{2+k}{3^{k}+1}<2\underset{k=n+1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{k}+\underset{k=n+1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}\frac{k}{3^{k}}$$
 now using$$\underset{k=0}{\overset{t}{\sum}}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{k}=\frac{1-\left(1/3\right)^{t+1}}{1-1/3}$$
 and$$\underset{k=0}{\overset{t}{\sum}}\frac{k}{3^{k}}=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{3^{-t}}{2}t-\frac{3^{1-t}}{4}$$
 and observing that$$\underset{k=n+1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}=\underset{k=0}{\overset{m}{\sum}}-\underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum}}$$
 you have your inequality. You can also use your calculations, because$$\underset{k=n+1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k}=\underset{k=0}{\overset{m}{\sum}}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k}-\underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum}}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k}=\frac{\left(2/3\right)^{n+1}-\left(2/3\right)^{m+1}}{1-2/3}<\epsilon$$
 $\forall\epsilon>0$
  and $m,\, n$
  large enough.